# JSON data from two tables without repeating joined table primary key

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have two models:

`Category` Model has: `id PRIMARY_KEY`, `category_name`, `...`

`Item` Model has: `id PRIMARY_KEY`, `item_name`, `category_id` (is id on category table),   `...`

I wish to achieve this JSON response:

```
Item:
{
    "id": 1,
    "item_name": "some item name",
    "category": {
        "id": "5",
        "category_name": "some category name"
    }
}
```

So far I have managed to achieve only response:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "item_name": "some item name",
    "category_id": "5", // i dont want it to appear here!
    "category": {
        "id": "5",
        "category_name": "some category name"
    }
}
```

With query:

```
$data = Item::select('id', 'item_name', 'category_id')->with(['category' => function ($query) {
            $query->select('id', 'category_name');
        }])->get();
return response()->json($data);
```

I tried `select('id', 'item_name')` instead of `select('id', 'item_name', 'category_id')`, but it fails, since it required 'category_id' for `with` to work. Any clean solutions to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to make it `hidden` in `Collection`:

```
$data = Item::select('id', 'item_name', 'category_id')->with(['category' =>     function ($query) {
            $query->select('id', 'category_name');
        }])->get()->makeHidden('category_id');
return response()->json($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you cannot remove `category_id` as it's needed to create the relationship. You can instead do something like this after you query and set `$data`.

```
$response = [];
$data->each(function ($value) use (&$response) { // pass $response by reference
    unset($value->category_id);
    $response[] = $value;
});
return response()->json($response);
```